# Can't access SearchKit as non-admin

Tags: permissions, searchkit

I can only access SearchKit as an admin. I have another role with the permissions "administer CiviCRM System", "administer CiviCRM Data", "SearchKit: edit and delete searches" and "FormBuilder: edit and delete forms". When I try to open SearchKit, I get the following error message: "Civi\API\Exception\UnauthorizedException: Authorization failed in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php on line 149". Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have "access CiviCRM backend and API"? That plus "SearchKit: edit and delete searches" works for me.

Comment: Hey Lars, thanks for your response. 
The user also has access to CiviCRM backend and API.

Comment: Seems like it must be something specific to your site as I just tried it here: http://demo-195-1u1e5.test-1.civicrm.org:8001/ with demo/demo (which only has those two permissions) and it works as expected.

Comment: I have found the issue. There was 1 SearchKit form with entity expenses and the permission "manage expenses" was not given to the user.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me, you should be able to access SearchKit in general even if specific searches require specific permissions. I'd post an issue on Gitlab.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've just posted an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4764